# process_template_response with new style django middleware

Tags: django

I used to use a middleware, just implementing process_template_response method.
I used this to alter response context before rendering.

With new style middlewares, I cant seem to able to use such method, it looks like we only have

```
self.process_request(request)
self.process_response(request, response)
```

Anybody knows how to alter response context before rendering, with a middleware?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#upgrading-pre-django-1-10-style-middleware

Comment: `process_template_response` hasn't changed in new-style middleware.